# How do NSEntityDescription and NSAttributeDescription work?

Tags: core-data, ios4, ipad

I am trying to understand how these things work : NSEntityDescription, NSAttributeDescription, attributeType.

I think these few lines of code work, since I get what I expect for the value of X.
Can some one tell me how I should modify the inner part of the loop, that is the line : X++;
in order to get the names and type of the properties in the entity : "myentity" ?

```
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::: EXPERIMENT    
MeDaSyAGAppDelegate *TheAppDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *TheContext=[TheAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *TheEntityDesc;
TheEntityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myentity" inManagedObjectContext:TheContext];
int X=0;
NSDictionary *attribs=[TheEntityDesc attributesByName];
for (NSAttributeDescription *eachA in [attribs allValues]) {
    X++;
}       
[self showMessageBox:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"X = %d.",X]];
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::: EXPERIMENT
```

Comment: Entity and attribute description are not things you usually spend much time dealing with in Core Data. They are largely used by Core Data behind the scenes. If your just starting out learning Core Data, I wouldn't recommend spending much time learning about them. It won't teach you anything practical.

Answer (score 2):

First: Format your code. See below.

Second: try to do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",eachA.name);//The name
NSLog(@"%d",[eachA attributeType])//The type, this is an integer
NSLog(@"%@",[eachA attributeValueClassName]);//Class name receiver
```

See:[NSAttributeDescription Class Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html)

Formatting: This looks better. (Attributes start with lower cases and use spaces)

```
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::: EXPERIMENT    
MeDaSyAGAppDelegate *theAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *theContext = [TheAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *theEntityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myentity" inManagedObjectContext:TheContext];
int X = 0;
NSDictionary *attribs = [theEntityDesc attributesByName];
for (NSAttributeDescription *eachA in [attribs allValues]) {
    X++;
}       
[self showMessageBox:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"X = %d.", X]];
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::: EXPERIMENT
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions were useful except that the first one ([eachA valueTransformerName]) only returns null. I was hopping to get the name of the property. Concerning my answers, I tried to accept, but it seems like I can' do it yet.